# Increment an integer in a Swift Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a dictionary in swift as seen here:

```
var pictures: [String:Int] = ["http://i.imgur.com/3VGLzoI.jpg":0, "http://i.imgur.com/wATPxvQ.png":0, "http://i.imgur.com/Q2XlngY.png":0]
```

Is there any way to increment or decrement the integer? If not, would a multidimensional array be a better option. I basically need the "vote" (integer) to stick with the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could do:

```
pictures["yourKey"]? += 1
```